# Can I connect multiple power supplies to a single outlet?

Tags: power-supply, wiring

I recently purchased two power supplies from Amazon:
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07TWW8Q73/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B005T6UJBU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I currently have both of them wired to two separate outlets.

**Is it possible to wire both of them to the same outlet?** Maybe like this?

[image: example]

**What would be the best way to split the wires safely?**

The power supply on the left is a 24V 15A AC/DC power supply.

The smaller one on the right is 5V 3A AC/DC power supply.

Comment: How did you connect one of them?

Comment: Are they permanently installed, that is, screwed to a wall or similar? Are they enclosed in a larger enclosure? How are you making those exposed terminals which are at mains voltage safe from accidentally being touched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrically, this will just work. Just wire them in parallel, like you have drawn. (I didn't check that you drew the wires going to the correct screws. I assume the drawing is correct.)

But **safety-wise**, I don't know the best way to make the parallel connection. If this was some little Arduino project I would just say to strip 3 wires, make a soldered connection and heatshrink it, but this is mains voltage so doing it *properly* does matter - you really need a strong connection that won't come undone accidentally, or you'll get a big spark and trip the breaker (best case) or electrocute yourself (worst case). If you are using fork terminals and two of them fit on one screw, then you might consider wiring the outlet to one power supply and then wiring that power supply to the other power supply, by putting the wires on the same screw, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I don't think this should be accepted since I haven't explained how to make the connection properly since I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire both power supplies to a household 120VAC outlet. However I recommend using separate power cables with each one terminated in a standard grounded plug. In this way the supplies will operate independently of each other and can be used at  different locations if needed. This is the same as plugging 2 separate lamps into a dual outlet or separated outlets.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the world of circuits. What do you mean by "separate power cables with each one terminated in a standard grounded plug"? Could you (or someone) please provide a simple diagram?

Comment: @Evan: Barry means you should use two power cords, one for each supply.  The cords should have standard plugs to plug into the common household outlets.

Comment: So something like this?      https://www.amazon.ca/Monoprice-14inch-16AWG-Power-Splitter/dp/B003L1AG8G/ref=sr_1_7?crid=QEDFMCEE7F18&keywords=110v+wire+splitter&qid=1666394323&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIyLjAwIiwicXNhIjoiMC4wMCIsInFzcCI6IjAuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=110v+wire+splitter%2Caps%2C97&sr=8-7

Comment: You really don't need two power cords.

Comment: @PeterBennett so you advocate the male plugs with exposed prongs which would then be live? So that they can be "plugged into the common household sockets". That seems extremely dangerous. extension cables have female ends for a reason...

Comment: @solar mike What are you saying makes no sense. The power supplies are not live. The socket is live which is why appliances come with male plugs. Again what we are recommending is no different than having 2 lamps with separate cords that plug into standard outlets.

Comment: @Barry power supplies that are not live? Not much use then.

Comment: @SolarMike: The supplies take in 120 VAC from the wall outlet and convert it to 24 VDC and 5 VDC - they do not make power themselves.  I suppose technically they should be called "power converters" or somesuch, but the common name is "Power supply".